# Cookie Id of one user copied from one browser to another browser - its hijacked - how to solve this issue

Tags: c#, cookies

I am logging as a user1 in chrome browser with valid credentials and I am logging as a user2 in IE browser. I am taking user2's cookie id from IE and pasting it in user1's Cookie id i.e (just deleting user1's cookie id and replaced with user2's cookie id). Now I am able to get the user2's account detail in chrome browser. Is there a way how to solve this issue?

Even if we manually copy the cookie from one browser to another browser - It should not hijack the user details of another browser.

Comment: Can you provide some more information? e.g. how you create the cookies... On the [ask] page you get some tips to increase your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the HttpOnly flag on your cookies, use data such as client ip and perhaps user agent to provide some variables to check against at the server, if something has changed then have them re-authenticate and only transmit over https.

Edit: Also if you are doing this on the same machine with the same user account remember that this isn't the best test of your web applications security, if someone got on my user account the browser would already have tonnes of remembered passwords for websites that a nefarious user could use to log in as me. If you transmit over https then data between client and server is encrypted and the risk is minimal for interception, if the hacker can get into you machine it becomes a whole new ball game